# Composer not allowing multiple version constrains with logical OR operator (|| double pipe)

Tags: composer-php

I have a project that I am trying to update a composer package (`myuser/mylib`) to version `6.0.*`. When trying to run `composer update` I get the following error message:

```
myuser/mypkg dev-master requires myuser/mylib ^5.5 ->> satisfiable by ...
```

The `myuser/mypkg` composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "myuser/mylib": "^5.5 || ^6.0"
  }
}
```

And my project's composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "myuser/mypkg": "dev-master",
    "myuser/mylib": "6.0.*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "http://github.com/myuser/mypkg.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why am I not able to upgrade to version `6.0.*`?

Comment: What does `php composer.phar prohibits myuser/mylib 6.0` output?  You may need to adjust `6.0` to an actual version number. It should provide details as to the conflicts, such as another package or platform version dependency. Such as your platform is php 5.6 and `userlib`  requires php ^7.0

Comment: From the looks of it though, `myuser/mypkg dev-master`, is limiting your dependency to `>= 5.5 <= 6.0`, So you would need to look at the `myuser/mypkg dev-master` composer.json to find your conflict